# Changing the text of the Leaflet zoom buttons

Tags: leaflet

I was wondering if there is a way to change the text of the Leaflet zoom buttons after they have been created.

I am aware that I could do the following:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("leaflet-control-zoom-in").innerHTML = 'text';
```

Or:

```
map.zoomControl.remove();
L.control.zoom({zoomInText: 'text'}).addTo(map);
```

But I was wondering if there is perhaps a more elegant way.

The docs do not mention a method but maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second method is using the standard api approach [zoom control](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#control-zoom). In order to avoid removing the  zoom control you can create the map with the [map zoomControl](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#map-zoomcontrol) option set to false and then continue with adding the customized zoom control.